# How to use Wayland in Gnome Flashback

Tags: 18.04, wayland, gnome-flashback

I would like to use Wayland in Gnome Flashback. My operating system is Ubuntu 18.04.

- It's possible to configure Metacity to use Wayland?
- If not, it's possible to configure Gnome Flashback to use Mutter window manager which supports Wayland?

EDIT: Is there any other window manager that supports Wayland and can be used with Gnome Flashback?

Answer (score 1):

Metacity is x11 window manager and that is not going to change. No, Metacity will not use Wayland.

It might be possible to use Mutter, but it is not supported. You would have to disable many things in gnome-flashback, otherwise there will be conflicts between gnome-flashback and mutter, because both will try to do same things, for example, manage monitors.

Comment: Is there some guide to use Mutter, or any other window manager that supports Wayland in Gnome Flashback?

Comment: @Tux, no! If you want to use GNOME Flashback then forget about Wayland. Why you so much want Wayland?

Comment: To avoid video tearing in my nvidia graphics card