# Make Gnome more traditional?

Tags: gnome, themes, mate, gnome-shell-extension, cinnamon

I've used Ubuntu since the earlier days, if you look me up in the Forums you'll see I joined pretty quickly.  All that is to say that I started with the traditional Gnome 2.x interface that Ubuntu used and I **liked** it. When Mate became available I switched to it but was not truly happy until Ubuntu-Mate appeared.  Again, this is to emphasize that I have a certain look and feel that I expect from my Ubuntu installation.  Sadly Gnome is no longer it.

I was looking at the Ubuntu sub in Reddit where someone posted another customization, this time rather than copying OSX they had recreated Windows 11.  I decided then and there to ask the question that had been bugging me for a while now--is there any way to make Gnome 42 look and behave like Gnome, in the traditional desktop with wayland support?  I have tried searching this before but due to the past vitriolic infighting over the changes in Gnome Shell there doesn't seem to be much written on the subject.  Any searches usually bring up the flamewars, not guides to getting what I'm trying to do.

I did locate this [guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/themes/debian-8-classic-ubuntu-gnome-2-desktop), but it's for an older version of Debian and I'm not sure how much still applies today to the latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I am currently running Ubuntu-Mate 20.04.4 LTS but am willing to install the default 22.04 LTS if there is a way to get that to look and behave more traditionally so I can try out Waydroid.  Thanks in advance for all advice given.

PS: I am aware that Mate is being ported to Wayland, but that process has taken some time and is not likely to be done in this year or even the next year or two. Also preemptively, Cinnamon does not have the classic menu, only its version of MintMenu so it is not an option.

Comment: Community note:  I see a couple of close-votes for "needs focus", but this really does feel like *one question*, even if it may (or may not) have multiple steps that would have to be done to answer.

Comment: This seems a non-trivial endeavor for Gnome. The codebase has changed a lot over 15 years, so it's not a matter of "*let's use this older method instead*" -- that older method simply isn't there anymore. My opinion is that your best bet is to volunteer to help Mate --which has a lot of that older Gnome2 code-- transition to Wayland. More help = Faster transition.

Comment: Recommending that I program it myself is not really an answer as I am not a programmer. This is less about an "older method" and more about the look and feel of the desktop.  Having tried Gnome again as advised below and discovered that the new theming breaks my attempts to set even the most basic theming by casting the settings application into a horrific white text on grey background I give up on Gnome again and will resume waiting for Mate to get there with Wayland. I just think it's sad that attempting to retain my desktop results in a parody of the memes about wallpaper changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you have the `GNOME Flashback` desktop that is like GNOME 2 you can install it via:

> sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback

Also, with gnome shell extension you can have access to `GNOME classic`:

> sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions

Comment: Does this also work with wayland?

I honestly don't know.  I've been with Mate for the last ten years.

Comment: This question seems to indicate it does not and is not likely to change: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013068/how-to-use-wayland-in-gnome-flashback

Comment: No `GNOME flashback` uses either compiz or metacity. But `GNOME classic` can be wayland powered!

Comment: Thanks. So how can I make Gnome Classic look and behave like Gnome 2.x?

Comment: That was just a piece of advices. Actually I started my Linux journey with Ubuntu on Unity and did not play with `gnome 2`. I though that `GNOME classic` was pretty close to `GNOME 2` but with the support of actual stuff like wayland.

Comment: This did not work as the recent changes in how themes work have left my eyeballs streaming as somehow making any changes gets me stuck with grey backgrounds and white text.  Thanks any way.  I guess I'll just return to my holding pattern and hope that Mate gets Wayland support soon.